# Always NAN as result in adding two values in Jquery

Tags: jquery, addition

Im having a hard time trying to find way/possible reason(s) of getting always NaN value of this formula and dont know why.. Here's my code:

```
var ebit = +$("#totalBillableAmount").text() - +$("#estCostPerDay").text();
alert(ebit);
```

Output: NaN

I also tried this code

```
var ebit = +parseFloat($("#totalBillableAmount").text()) - +parseFloat($("#estCostPerDay").text());
    alert(ebit);
    $("#estEbitPerDay").append(ebit);

   $("#totalBillableAmount").text()= "2,013.700";
   $("#estCostPerDay").text() = "5,557.82";
```

Output: -3

Please Help !

Comment: have you tried parseInt($("#totalBillableAmount").text()) for example?

Comment: ... and if your numbers are not integers, you can use `parseFloat()`.

Comment: You must have something other than numbers inside of the text.

Comment: parseInt and Float seems have the same output "-3"

Comment: Alije, that doesn't mean that it is ACTUALLY a number. View my secondary fiddle in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

### You have commas in your numbers. These are interpreted like `strings`

**You are attempting to add strings. Try using something like:**

`parseFloat($('#totalBillableAmount').text() - $('#estCostPerDay').text());`

**Your method is doing this:**

**(ie. `"5,557.82" - "2,013.700"`)**

**Not this:**

**(ie. `5557.82 - 2013.700`)**

---

### **EDIT** - This is the answer you want.

#### http://jsfiddle.net/Wq96P/9/

**Travis is right. You must have some non-numerical character in your `div`s - namely `commas`.**

Comment: Just cause it works in the fiddle, doesn't mean a real world browser will interpret it the same. [LOOK AT THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Wq96P/4/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Wq96P/5/ The conversion is implicit. The issue is not having some regular number as the text. The issue is that there is something other than numbers in the text.

Comment: Now that I played with it, I forgot NaN IS a number... good call out.

Comment: You're right, after analyzing the data i realized that it's all string :) Thanks. It's now working .

Comment: Another additional question sir. When i tried to use your solution code, for example the two numbers are 22,150.7 and 2,013.70, but the output was 22.00.. Any ideas here?

Comment: If you wanted a function to replace the commas with nothing, use Regex to do so [Fiddle with regex to accept values with commas](http://jsfiddle.net/Wq96P/11/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `parseInt()`.

```
var ebit = parseInt($("#totalBillableAmount").text()) - +parseInt($("#estCostPerDay").text());
alert(ebit);
```

Comment: If you're using `parseInt`, you no longer need the `+` at the beginning of each number since that is to implicitly convert each string into a number.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solve :)

Just have this code..

```
   var totalBillAmt = parseFloat($("#totalBillableAmount").text().replace(",", ""))  +    parseFloat($("#estCostPerDay").text().replace(",", ""));
```